Elliptic curve with rational points that satisfy certain condition

For fixed $t\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\left\{1\right\}$, I want to find conditions of $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Q}$
$\mid\ \left(a\neq b\ \wedge\ ab < 0\right)$ of the Elliptic Curve
$$
E:\ y^{2} = x\left(x - a\right)\left(x - b\right)
$$ which make $E$ to have two rational points, $$(x_1,y_1)\ \mbox{and}\ (x_2,y_2),\qquad x_1,x_2\neq 0,a,b
$$
satisfying $y_1/x_1 = ty_2/x_2$.
By 1, the set of rational points is dense
( if it is infinite ) in $E(\mathbb{R})$, so we can always find $$(x_1,y_1)\ \mbox{and}\ (x_2,y_2)\quad \mbox{with}\quad {y_1 \over x_1} \approx t\,{y_2 \over x_2}
$$
However, I cannot go further than this.

Can anyone please help ?.

This is kind of an interesting thing to ask for. What's motivating you to go look for this?

I struggle to understand what would constitute an answer to this question more than the obvious "after rescaling so that $b=1$ there is a surface covering $E \times E$ defined by $x_1 y_2 = t x_2 y_1$ and you are looking for rational points." I haven't checked anything about the geometry of this surface, but by construction it has Kodaira dimension $\geq 0$ so it's not going to be very easy to say anything in general, I think.

If you fix $a,b$ then you're asking to determine the points on a genus $5$ curve.

@KReiser Hello, I got this from the "Heron's triangle problem". This is about generating Heron's triangle with two rational median lengths. After proper parametrization of the triangle, one can get two quartic curves $^2=_1(),^2=_2()$ and can combine them into one elliptic curve above.

@Mummytheturkey Thank you for the comment. Could you explain why this is genus 5?

@Balajisb Hello, so you mean that I should first find one non-trivial rational $x_2$ and solve the equation you gave?

@Balajisb Thank you. I have one question. Can we guarantee that $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are on the elliptic curve $E$ if $x_1$ and $x_2$ satisfy your equation?

@aleph0 Sure, I can elaborate. For fixed $a,b$ you are asking abound the curve cut out by $ y^2 = x(x -a)(x-b)$, $v^2 = u(u-a)(u-b)$ and $xv =tuy$ in $\mathbb{A}^4_{x,y,u,v}$ (or, better, in $E \times E$). This has three irreducible components -- two of which are birational to $E$ and correspond to "trivial solutions" given by $x=y=0$ or $u=v=0$. The final irreducible component is a curve of genus $5$ by a standard application of Riemann--Hurwitz.

@Balajisb I'm still curious. Let me emphasize our conjecture.
"$x_1$ and $x_2\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfy $\frac{(x_1-a)(x_1-b)x_2}{(x_2-a)(x_2-b)x_1}=t^2$. Then 1. $y_1$ and $y_2\in\mathbb{Q}$ and 2. $\frac{y_1}{x_1}=\pm t\frac{y_2}{x_2}$ where $y_i^2=x_i(x_i-a)(x_i-b), (i=1,2)$."
2 is obvious. However, I cannot show 1. What we can only see is $\frac{y_1}{y_2}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Does this implies $y_1$ and $y_2\in\mathbb{Q}$ in elliptic curve cases?

@Balajisb Thank you. But I also hope $y_1$ and $y_2$ to be rational. Do we need more than $\frac{(x_1-a)(x_1-b)x_2}{(x_2-a)(x_2-b)x_1}=t^2$?

@Balajisb I really appreciate your help.

COMMENT.-To help you, let me change notations for a better understanding of your problem and explain why I think it would be better to limit yourself to asking for a particular example of what you are asking for in general.
QUESTION.- Let $1\ne t\in \mathbb Q$; find conditions of distinct rational $A,B$ with $AB\lt0$ such that the cubic $\Gamma:y^2=x(x-A)(x-B)$ have two rational points $(a,b),(c,d)$ distinct of the three obvious torsion points in the $x$- coordinates and that they meet the condition $\dfrac dc=\dfrac ba t$.
It would be better, I think, asked about a particular example satisfying your problem. A general answer I am sure is not possible. Note first that $$\dfrac dc=\dfrac ba t\iff t=\frac{ad}{bc}$$ so what you are asking is about two points in an elliptic curve of the form of $\Gamma$ such that the above quotient be equal to an arbitrary rational.
The first heavy problem to solve is to find conditions on $A,B$ such that the rank of $\Gamma$ be $\ge 1$ or at least that  it have a torsión group of more than the three obvious ones (for example $y^2=x^3+2x^2-3x$ which have the four non-trivial torsion points $(-1, \pm2),(3,\pm6)$). This problem cannot be solved as far as I know.
The second (quite) heavy problem is that having $(a,b)$ it is not posible to know if there exist another point $(c,d)$ such that
$t=\dfrac ab\times\dfrac dc$ (for example, It could be that $(c,d)$ is such that $(c,d)=n(a,b)$ in which case $(c,d)$ is the numerical value of polynomials of degree $n^2$ so what can you if the integer $n$ is large? (which goes without saying that $t$ could have its numerator and denominator large, since it is arbitrary.
